# HTML Form doesnt adjust to browser

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a HTML-Form in my ASP.NET MVC5 application.
My Problem is as following:
I want the form to adjust as the browser re-adjusts.
For Example: I have 3 Input-boxes with their labels for each.
On my Desktop-Browser, they should lay side by side on one (hypothetic) line.
If I shrink my browserwindow, they should get more and more among themselves.

So if the 3th box doesn't have enough place, it should get down under the first textbox, and then if the 2nd textbox hasn't got enough space either, it should get under the first textbox and press the 3th textbox even further down.

So first, I have 3 Textboxes like this:

[neben http://image-upload.de/image/qMO7Lb/1f0841a821.png](http://image-upload.de/image/qMO7Lb/1f0841a821.png)

If the browser resizes, I want the boxes align like this:

[image: unter]
<sub>(source: [image-upload.de](http://image-upload.de/image/WuFpso/a5d35657ab.png))</sub>

I have the following code in razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       <div class="form-control">
            <label for="dd1">Dropdown1</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.dd1, new SelectList(Model.listDd1))
       </div>
       <div class="form-control">
            <label for="dd2">Dropdown2</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.dd2, new SelectList(Model.listDd2))
       </div>
       <div class="form-control">
            <label for="tb1">Textbox1</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tb1)
       </div>
}
```

Does anyone have a corresponding Twitter-Bootstrap-Class for my purpose? I didn't find anything at google/so/whereever.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) which provides exactly this functionality.

You could write something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I went through this linked document many times, I had implemented it this way, it didn't work.
But now, It works.
Black Magic? :P
I will accept your answer as the right one, thank you :)